# same SNP rs# referenced to be found in two different genes

Tags: snp, gwas

Two GWAS papers have referenced the same SNP (rs7442295), but one states it's found in the gene GLUT9 and the other states it's found in SCL2A9. The ncbi dbSNP says it's in SCL2A9, and I thought that the rs number was unique to each SNP, so how can it be in two different genes? I'm really new to GWAS, so it might be a really stupid question, but any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NCBI dbSNP entry](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=7442295) shows rs7442295 to be in the gene SLC2A9, not S*CL*2A9 stated in the original question.

As the [Wikipedia article for SLC2A9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLC2A9) says, synonymous names for SLC2A9 include:

> solute carrier family 2 (facilitated glucose transporter), member 9, GLUT9, GLUTX, UAQTL2, URATv1, solute carrier family 2 member 9

So GLUT9 and SLC2A9 refer to the same gene, and the two papers are not in conflict about the location of the rs7442295 SNP.

Answer (score 0):

Both mutations have caused the same changes in serum uric acid. In other words, one of those papers is older. Those are the same genes.